# How to use awk variable in search?

Tags: shell, awk

How to use awk variable in search?

```
Name="jony"
awk -v name="$Name" '/name/ {print $0}' file
```

this will search for string `name`, not for `$Name` which is actually `jony`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct, `awk` won't recogize variables in `/ /`. You can do:

```
Name="jony"
awk -v name="$Name" '$0 ~ name' file
```

Since `print` is `awk's` default behavior we can avoid using it here.

Comment: can you just explain what ~ is doing here?

i tried this, and it is not working.

> `echo "Hi this is jony" | awk '$0 ~ jony'
  
 > output :  Hi this is jony`

>`echo "Hi this is jony" | awk '$0 ~ holmes'
>output : Hi this is jony`

i don't understand why it is printing the line even if there is no "holmes" in it.

Comment: From the guide: `~ (tilde), ~ operator Regular expressions can also be used in matching expressions. These expressions allow you to specify the string to match against; it need not be the entire current input record. The two operators `~' and `!~' perform regular expression comparisons. Expressions using these operators can be used as patterns, or in if, while, for, and do statements.`

Comment: @Jagan When you do `echo "Hi this is jony" | awk '$0 ~ holmes'` `awk` sees `homes` as an undefined variable and hence prints the line. If you want `awk` to consider it as a literal string you will need to quote it.

Answer (score 1):

Hope I understood problem correctly:
Why wont you try following one:

```
awk '/'"$Name"'/ { print } ' testfile
```

Comment: No, never do this. It's very buggy and error-prone. Use `-v` to set variables, or see the comp.unix.shell FAQ http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24 for reasonable alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

When writing an AWK one-liner, you could quote the script with either the single quotes or double quotes. In the latter case the shell does all the substitution directly so that you do not need to pass the variable into the script via `-v` option:

```
Name="jony"
awk "/$Name/" file
# this works. after shell has performed substitutions, the line looks like
awk "/jony/" file
```

[bad!] Or even without quotes if the name does not contain spaces:

```
awk /$Name/ file
```

All the simplicity vanishes as soon as you want to use $ in the script, including awk special variables that use $0, $1, etc, because you will have to escape the dollar sign to prevent shell variable expansion.

```
awk "/$Name/ {print \$0}"
```

In addition you will have to escape the double quotes to add literal text to the script. Looks clumsy:

```
awk "/$Name/ {print \"Found in: \" \$0}"
```

To crown it all, negating regular expression with double quotes will cause a shell error:

```
awk "!/$Name/"
#error> ... event not found ...
```

The error will happen if $Name itself contains ! sign. This makes using double quotes unreliable.

So, to be on the safe side, prefer single quotes :)